# simple merge sort in python

Tags: python, mergesort

iam learning python so sorry for not coding the pythonic way
iam trying to make a merge sort but its not working
i looked at the debugger it seems the problem it doesnt do line  `arr1[i] = arr[s+i]` and jumb back to the mergeSort function idont know why

```
def mergeSort(arr,s,e):
    if s >= e: return
    mid = s + (e-s)//2; 
    mergeSort(arr,s,mid)
    mergeSort(arr,mid+1,e)
    merge(arr,s,mid,e)


def merge(arr,s,mid,e):
        arr1 = []
        arr2 = [] 
        n = mid -s + 1
        m = e - mid
        for i in range (0,n):
            arr1[i] = arr[s+i]
        for i in range (0,m):
            arr2[i] = arr[mid + i + 1]
                
        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = s
        while i <  len(arr1) and  j < len(arr2):
            if(arr1[i] < arr2[j]):
                arr[k] = arr1[i]
                i+=1
            else:
                arr[k] = arr2[j]
                j+=1 
            k+=1
        while(i < len(arr1)):
            arr[k] = arr1[i]
            i+=1
            k+=1
        while(j < len(arr2)):
            arr[k] = arr2[j]
            j+=1
            k+=1

arr = [1,5,0,3,-15,99,1500,-1500,66,120]
mergeSort(arr,0,len(arr))
print(arr)
```

The error I get is:

```
line 41, in merge arr1[i] = arr[s+i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: can you share the input for which it is giving error?

Answer (score 0):

with `arr1[i] = arr[s+i]` you're trying to update the value on index i, but that value may or may not exist. If you try to update that doesn't exist, you get `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

You can work around it by wrapping it in a try-catch block:

```py
            try:
              arr1[i] = arr[s+i]
            except:
              arr1.append(arr[s+i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make variable `k` to `0` along with `i` and `j`

[reference](https://github.com/HarshPanchal18/Sorting-Methods/blob/main/Python/PyMergeSort.py) - get easy with **Recursion**